# view not updated after the ng-repeat looping array is updated in the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a table with my column names and records in arrays 'headers' and 'records' respectively.

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="dataset">
       <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th ng-repeat="header in headers">{{ header }}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="record in records.slice(1,11)">
                <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                <td ng-repeat="cell in record">{{cell}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
 </table>
```

Both the records are declared null in the beginning and updated after the user selects a csv to read. Once the arrays have the values, inside the controller, I'm doing -

```
$scope.headers = headers;
$scope.records = records;
```

But the elements are not created in the view. In console > elements , the ng-repeat directive appears commented.

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="dataset">
       <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <!-- ngRepeat: header in headers -->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- ngRepeat: record in records.slice(1,11) -->
        </tbody>
</table>
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Here's the complete script :

```
    var VizApp = angular.module('VizApp', []);

    VizApp.config(function($routeProvider){

        $routeProvider
            .when('/overview',{
                    controller : 'VizController',
                    templateUrl : 'views/overview.html'
            })
            .when('/options', {
                controller : 'VizController',
                templateUrl : 'views/options.html'
            })
            .when('/charts', {
                controller : 'VizController',
                templateUrl : 'views/charts.html'
            })
            .otherwise({redirectTo : '/overview'})
    });

    var controllers = {};
    controllers.VizController = function($scope){

        var headers = [];
        var records = [];

        var csvPath;
        var cgiPath = '/cgi-bin/cgiTest.py';

        $scope.getCsv = function(selection){
            //Triggered when the user choses a csv from a file input

            csvPath = 'csvs/' + selection[0].files[0].name;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: csvPath,
                dataType: "text",       
                success: function(data) {
                    processData(data);
                }
            });
        };

        function processData(allText) {

            var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
            headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');  

            $.each(allTextLines.slice(1,allTextLines.length), function(i,thisRecord){
                records[i] = thisRecord.split(',');
            });

            console.log("Comes here");
            $scope.headers = headers;
            $scope.records = records; 
            //If I do a $scope.headers = ['a','b'] here, I still don't see two columns made with headers a and b

        }
        //If I do a $scope.headers = ['a','b'] here, I see two columns made with headers a and b
    };

    VizApp.controller(controllers);

</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please give your scripts two

Comment: Added the complete script!

Comment: try changing $scope.headers = [] , to $scope.allheaders = {}; and then => $scope.allheaders.headers = [];

I mean put your array inside of an object

Comment: Didnt work. Thanks though. It's solved using the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your code which updates scope in `$scope.$apply()` like this:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
       $scope.headers = headers;
       $scope.records = records; 
});
```

You need to do that because you update scope in asynchronous callback which runs in different javascript turn about which angularjs does not know. Check [this post](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) for more information.

Another way to go is to use angularjs `$http` service. In this case you won't need to wrap your scope update in `$scope.$apply` because angularjs does it for you.

```
controllers.VizController = function($scope, $http){

        var headers = [];
        var varType = [];
        var records = [];
        var parameters = { 'xAxisVar' : '', 'yAxisVar' : '', 'sliceByVar' : '',    'chartByVar' : '', 'groups' : '', 'slices' : ''};

        var csvPath;
        var cgiPath = '/cgi-bin/cgiTest.py';


        $scope.getCsv = function(selection){
            //Triggered when the user choses a csv from a file input

            csvPath = 'csvs/' + selection[0].files[0].name;
            $http({method: 'GET', url: csvPath}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                 processData(data);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            });
        };

        function processData(allText) {

            var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
            headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');  

            $.each(allTextLines.slice(1,allTextLines.length), function(i,thisRecord){
                records[i] = thisRecord.split(',');
            });

            $scope.headers = headers;
            $scope.records = records; 


        }
    };
```